# Tensorboard: filtering histograms by iterations/steps

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is it possible to filter histograms in Tensorboard by range of steps?

For instance, I want to display histogram of weights from 270 to 300 iterations, it's convenient to check the values where the overfitting gap is started.

[image]